# How to fix SIGSEGV which prevents MVC application running in Mono

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, mono, mod-mono, xsp

ASP.NET MVC application is installed in Debian server using Apache and mod_mono.

Trying to start it causes SIGSEGV exception in Mono. Apache error.log contains

```
[Wed Mar 06 22:07:13 2019] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) mod_mono/3.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
Listening on: /tmp/.mod_mono_server4
Root directory: /
Stacktrace:

[Wed Mar 06 22:07:35 2019] [error] (70014)End of file found: read_data failed
[Wed Mar 06 22:07:35 2019] [error] Command stream corrupted, last command was 1
Listening on: /tmp/.mod_mono_server4
Root directory: /
Stacktrace:


Native stacktrace:

    /usr/bin/mono() [0x4accca]
    /usr/bin/mono() [0x5040fe]
    /usr/bin/mono() [0x4275d7]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xf0a0) [0x7f47845d30a0]
    /usr/bin/mono() [0x47aad9]
    /usr/bin/mono() [0x50fcb8]
    /usr/bin/mono() [0x510253]
    /usr/bin/mono() [0x425efc]
    /usr/bin/mono() [0x4af809]
    /usr/bin/mono() [0x4b0117]
    [0x411fe68c]

Debug info from gdb:


=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

How to fix this so that application can run ?
Same server also contains other application created with older ASP.NET MVC which runs OK.

Mono was installed using Debian package:

```
mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 4.6.2 (Stable 4.6.2.7/08fd525 Mon Nov 14 12:30:00 UTC 2016)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       altstack
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  amd64
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
        GC:            sgen
```

Comment: Assuming you've installed everything correctly then you can try the following to debug it https://www.mono-project.com/docs/debug+profile/debug/

Comment: How I can excatly debug this issue, this link in very generic ? I posted related question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55085128/how-to-compile-mono-in-debian-wheezy

Comment: Sorry, my bad -- its the GDB section that you'll need.

Comment: I havent used GDB. How to find line in Mono source code which causes SIGSEGV ? Is 0x411fe68c instruction address offset ? How to translate it to line number ?

Comment: Hey, I believe they are yes. You should be bale to use the gdb call mono_pmip to find out what the method name is at each address identified in the stack trace.