# How to compile Mono in Debian Wheezy

Tags: c++, cmake, mono, debian

Trying to fix Mono SIGSEGV as described in

[How to fix SIGSEGV which prevents MVC application running in Mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55031536/how-to-fix-sigsegv-which-prevents-mvc-application-running-in-mono)

I tried to compile newer mono from source codes:

```
wget http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/mono-5.18.0.225.tar.bz2
cd /usr/local/src
tar jxf mono-5.18.0.225.tar.bz2
cd mono-5.18.0.225
./autogen.sh --prefix=/opt/m518
```

autogen stops with error that CMake 2.8.10 is required:

```
....
Making install in btls
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/mono-5.18.0.268/mono/btls'
mkdir -p build-shared
(cd build-shared && CC="gcc" CXX="g++" /usr/bin/cmake -D CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/usr/bin/make -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/opt/m518 -D BTLS_ROOT:PATH=/usr/local/src/mono-5.18.0.268/external/boringssl -D SRC_DIR:PATH=/usr/local/src/mono-5.18.0.268/mono/btls -D BTLS_CFLAGS:STRING=""  -DBTLS_ARCH="x86_64" -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=1 /usr/local/src/mono-5.18.0.268/mono/btls)
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
  CMake 2.8.10 or higher is required.  You are running version 2.8.9
```

I havent found CMake 2.8.10 version for my debian.
So I tried to compile CMake using

```
cd /usr/local/src
wget  https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.14.0-rc4/cmake-3.14.0-rc4.tar.gz
tar -xzf cmake-3.14.0-rc4.tar.gz
cd cmake-3.14.0-rc4
./configure
make
```

but make fails with error

```
g++  -std=gnu++11      -I/usr/local/src/cmake-3.14.0-rc4/Bootstrap.cmk   -I/usr/local/src/cmake-3.14.0-rc4/Source   -I/usr/local/src/cmake-3.14.0-rc4/Source/LexerParser   -I/usr/local/src/cmake-3.14.0-rc4/Utilities  -c /usr/local/src/cmake-3.14.0-rc4/Source/cmCommands.cxx -o cmCommands.o
In file included from /usr/local/src/cmake-3.14.0-rc4/Source/cmFindBase.h:11:0,
                 from /usr/local/src/cmake-3.14.0-rc4/Source/cmFindPathCommand.h:11,
                 from /usr/local/src/cmake-3.14.0-rc4/Source/cmFindFileCommand.h:8,
                 from /usr/local/src/cmake-3.14.0-rc4/Source/cmCommands.cxx:29:
/usr/local/src/cmake-3.14.0-rc4/Source/cmFindCommon.h:28:3: error: looser throw specifier for ‘virtual cmFindCommon::~cmFindCommon()’
In file included from /usr/local/src/cmake-3.14.0-rc4/Source/cmAddCompileDefinitionsCommand.h:11:0,
                 from /usr/local/src/cmake-3.14.0-rc4/Source/cmCommands.cxx:7:
/usr/local/src/cmake-3.14.0-rc4/Source/cmCommand.h:36:11: error:   overriding ‘virtual cmCommand::~cmCommand() noexcept (true)’
In file included from /usr/local/src/cmake-3.14.0-rc4/Source/cmCommands.cxx:34:0:
/usr/local/src/cmake-3.14.0-rc4/Source/cmForEachCommand.h:22:3: error: looser throw specifier for ‘virtual cmForEachFunctionBlocker::~cmForEachFunctionBlocker()’
In file included from /usr/local/src/cmake-3.14.0-rc4/Source/cmForEachCommand.h:12:0,
                 from /usr/local/src/cmake-3.14.0-rc4/Source/cmCommands.cxx:34:
/usr/local/src/cmake-3.14.0-rc4/Source/cmFunctionBlocker.h:29:11: error:   overriding ‘virtual cmFunctionBlocker::~cmFunctionBlocker() noexcept (true)’
In file included from /usr/local/src/cmake-3.14.0-rc4/Source/cmCommands.cxx:81:0:
/usr/local/src/cmake-3.14.0-rc4/Source/cmWhileCommand.h:22:3: error: looser throw specifier for ‘virtual cmWhileFunctionBlocker::~cmWhileFunctionBlocker()’
In file included from /usr/local/src/cmake-3.14.0-rc4/Source/cmForEachCommand.h:12:0,
                 from /usr/local/src/cmake-3.14.0-rc4/Source/cmCommands.cxx:34:
/usr/local/src/cmake-3.14.0-rc4/Source/cmFunctionBlocker.h:29:11: error:   overriding ‘virtual cmFunctionBlocker::~cmFunctionBlocker() noexcept (true)’
make: *** [cmCommands.o] Error 1
---------------------------------------------
Error when bootstrapping CMake:
Problem while running make
---------------------------------------------
Log of errors: /usr/local/src/cmake-3.14.0-rc4/Bootstrap.cmk/cmake_bootstrap.log
---------------------------------------------
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

I trid also to compile CMake older version

```
cd /usr/local/src
wget https://cmake.org/files/v3.10/cmake-3.10.0.tar.gz
tar -xzf cmake-3.10.0.tar.gz
cd cmake-3.10.0
./configure
make
```

but same error occurs.

I have also very old Debian Squeeze in other computer. It does not have cmake installed but compiles Mono without issues. Compiling in Wheezy throws error in cmake is not installed.

I to compile newer mono or if this helps, newer cmake in Debian Wheezy ?

Comment: Is the question about building Mono or CMake? 2 of 3 attempts described in the question are unrelated to Mono...

Comment: Ultimate goal is to run MVC applicaton in Mono. Currently it causes SIGSEGV in mono. Question asks for this solution and describes one way which may solve this. This way requires compiling CMake which fails. Compiling CMake is stopper issue preventing Mono to compile.

Comment: Mono 5.x has been accepted in debian recently, just upgrade to a version of Debian that has it

Comment: Upgrading is a lot of work. I compiled Mono 5 in old Debian squeeze without issues. Squeeze does not have cmake installed. Why cmake is required in debian wheezy and how to compile mono in wheezy ?

Comment: don't upgrade, install a new debian version from scratch; it's going to be much less work than solving this problem; why do you need a new version of Mono instead of the one that Wheezy brings?

Comment: If Mono needs a minimum version of 2.8.10 for CMake, why don't you [just download that](https://cmake.org/files/v2.8/cmake-2.8.10.tar.gz)?

Comment: @knocte  Trying to run application in Wheezy mono causes SIGSEGV as described in referenced question and application does not start. I thought that maybe Mono new version works.

Comment: @nega I donwloaded CMake as you recommended. This containf source code and question is that this source code wont compile, compile time error occurs.

Comment: CMake 2.8.x compiles perfectly fine on Wheezy with the default `gcc/g++`.

Comment: In my case it does not compile. ´g++  -std=gnu++11      -I/usr/local/src/cmake-3.14.0-rc4/Bootstrap.cmk   -I/usr/local/src/cmake-3.14.0-rc4/Source   -I/usr/local/src/cmake-3.14.0-rc4/Source/LexerParser   -I/usr/local/src/cmake-3.14.0-rc4/Utilities  -c /usr/local/src/cmake-3.14.0-rc4/Source/cmCommands.cxx -o cmCommands.o´ throws error  shown in question. I asked how to solve this. Compiling CMake 2.8 throws same error